# is it possible to install qemu inside linux ami on ec2?

Tags: centos, amazon-ec2, qemu

well i tried to install it but gont an error .

```
kernel-2.6.35.11-83.9.amzn1.i686 has missing requires of mkinitrd >= ('0', '6.0.91', None)
```

Comment: You solved your issue? This means it is possible to run qemu on ec2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the premade Amazon linux images.  They trim many of the default CentOS libraries from their local repositories.  You can manually add the CentOS repositories back in and it should help you find any missing packages.

Answer (score 3):

For those interested in where the default CentOS repositories are:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-5 - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=i386&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1
[updates]
name=CentOS-5 - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=i386&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/updates/i386/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1
[extras]
name=CentOS-5 - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=5&arch=i386&repo=extras
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/extras/i386/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
priority=1
#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
```

GPG key

```
rpm --import http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
```

Source: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=196807